# Gmail content downloader/parser

Tags: python, email, parsing, gmail, imap

I'm trying to download all my email content from gmail using a python script but this is what I found. I tried it and it's only downloading the attachments into pdf files. Is there a way to modify it to download just the email content. I'm also trying to parse just the url links in my emails.

```
import email
import imaplib
import os


server = 'imap.gmail.com'
user = '@gmail.com'
password = 'pass'
outputdir = 'lolz'
subject = 'Order Completed' #subject line of the emails you want to download attachments from

def connect(server, user, password):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    m.login(user, password)
    m.select()
    return m

def downloaAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir):
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(BODY.PEEK[])")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        return
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None:
            open(outputdir + '/' + part.get_filename(), 'wb').write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

#download attachments from all emails with a specified subject line
def downloadAttachments(subject):
    m = connect(server, user, password)
    m.select("Inbox")
    typ, msgs = m.search(None, '(SUBJECT "' + subject + '")')
    msgs = msgs[0].split()
    for emailid in msgs:
        downloaAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir)

downloadAttachments(subject)
```

Comment: maybe [this] (https://medium.com/@yernagulahemanth/download-emails-from-gmail-using-python-31e9bc62e501) can help you

Comment: im not really good at python and his github is down

Comment: Yes, that certainly is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I just used thunderbird and downloaded it that way